# Magento 2 Migrate from Google Universal Analytics to GA4

Tags: magento2, google-analytics

Google Universal Analytics will be *going away* in July 2023 to be replaced with Google Analytics 4.

> On July 1, 2023, standard Universal Analytics properties will stop
> processing new hits. If you still rely on Universal Analytics, we
> recommend that you prepare to use Google Analytics 4 going forward.

What is the best way to migrate from Google Universal Analytics to GA4 in older Magento 2.4 versions whilst still retaining all the eCommerce analysis provided by the current Universal Analytics module?

*I am not interested in links to commercial modules.*

Comment: Instruction on how to configure GA4 with GTM for Magento 2 Store. Easy Step by Step guide configures GA4 Extension in your Magento 2. [https://www.magedelight.com/resources/how-to-configure-ga4-with-gtm-in-magento-2-store/](https://www.magedelight.com/resources/how-to-configure-ga4-with-gtm-in-magento-2-store/)

Answer (score 2):

If you using Magento version 2.4.5 or higher, Magento has already released a new module called **GoogleGtag** that support GA4 and also keeps the old ** GoogleAnalytics** module to support **Google Universal Analytics**

Alternatively, if you need to use an alternative module or for older Magento versions, there is a free module available by Yireo that supports versions 2.3.7 or higher and 2.4.1 or higher.

This module is a great module and highly recommended by the Magento community. You can take a look at: https://github.com/yireo/Yireo_GoogleTagManager2

Comment: Thanks I was referring to < 2.4.5 - making the 2.4.5 module available would be a great idea.

Comment: @paj I've added a great free module that supports GA4 to my answer :).